# MySQL: How to check if a provided value is a number/ integer or letters?

Tags: mysql, sql, php-5.3

How can I check if a provided value is a number/ integer or letters?

For instance, this is my working SQL,

```
SELECT 
    p.*

FROM page AS p

WHERE p.title = 'home'

AND IF(CONVERT('7', SIGNED INTEGER) IS NOT NULL, p.parent_id != p.page_id, p.parent_id = p.page_id)
```

'**7**' is variable, sometime it is a number, sometimes it is '**self**'.

So when it is a number, then `p.parent_id != p.page_id`

Else `p.parent_id = p.page_id`

But I can get it right as my SQL query returns always  `p.parent_id != p.page_id`.

Comment: If the variable is non-numeric, is it always `'self'`?  If so, can you not simply invert your thinking and check `IF(var = 'self', ...`?

Comment: yes I think I could do that too! thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`REGEXP`.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

```
AND CASE
    WHEN ('7' REGEXP '^[0-9]+$') THEN
      p.parent_id != p.page_id
    ELSE p.parent_id = p.page_id
END
```

The reason your `CONVERT()` fails to work as expected is that a non-numeric string will always be cast as 0, rather than NULL.

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT('7a', SIGNED INTEGER);
+-------------------------------+
| CONVERT('7a', SIGNED INTEGER) |
+-------------------------------+
|                             7 |
+-------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT CONVERT('self', SIGNED INTEGER);
+---------------------------------+
| CONVERT('self', SIGNED INTEGER) |
+---------------------------------+
|                               0 | <-- non-numeric strings always cast to 0
+---------------------------------+
```

Your method may work if you compare against 0 instead of NULL, but I don't have a good way to test.  However, this fails if the value actually is 0, wherein you'll get the wrong comparison back.

```
AND IF(CONVERT('7', SIGNED INTEGER) <> 0, p.parent_id != p.page_id, p.parent_id = p.page_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

```
WHERE 
     '7' REGEXP '[[:digit:]]+' AND p.parent_id != p.page_id 
  OR '7' REGEXP '[[:alpha:]]+' AND p.parent_id = p.page_id
```

or more optimal

```
WHERE 
     '7' REGEXP '[[:digit:]]+' AND p.parent_id != p.page_id 
  OR '7' = 'self'              AND p.parent_id = p.page_id
```

assuming implicit cast `1` to `TRUE` and `0` to `FALSE` by mysql.

Comment: `SELECT '7abcd' REGEXP '[[:digit:]]+'` returns `1`. You need to anchor your regex.